# use of inner.html

Tags: javascript, html, flash

Apologies for the strange format of this question. I've asked a couple of similar questions recently and am still at a loss. I REALLY don't know how most of this works, and I've been trying to follow various tutorials etc. on places like W3Schools.com, and with the help of people here, and although I don't fully understand, I think I'm almost there.

What I'm trying to do is ONLY play a piece of video if it's the first time a visitor has arrived at the site (but it's a bit special - it's transparent, and needs to float on the page).

The code below correctly sets a cookie if one doesn't exist, and checks for it on the user visiting the site. The bit I have a problem with is the syntax of the line that starts:

```
document.getElementById('video').innerHTML =
```

If I comment that line out, all the other cookie stuff works fine, so I'm hoping that someone can help. the errors that the firefox error console gives are: unexpected end of xml source  and checkCookie is not defined

I also tried throwing quotes around the whole lot, but it made no real difference.

Here is the code, and thank you all in advance. Rob.

```
<div id="video" style="position:absolute;top:125px;left:-67px;z-index:10000000"> </div>
<script src="AC_RunActiveContent.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getCookie(c_name)
{
  var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");

  for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
  {
    x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
    y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
    x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");

    if (x==c_name)
    {
      return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
  var exdate = new Date();
  exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
  var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
  document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function checkCookie()
{
  var username=getCookie("username");

  if (username!=null && username!="")
  {
    alert("Welcome again " + username);
  }
  else
  {
    username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");

    if (username!=null && username!="")
    {
      setCookie("username",username,7);
      document.getElementById('video').innerHTML = <script type="text/javascript"> AC_FL_RunContent ('codebase','http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0','width','320','height','220','id','HTIFLVPlayer','src','HTIFLVPlayer','flashvars','&MM_ComponentVersion=1&skinName=HTI_Skin&streamName=nigel&autoPlay=true&autoRewind=true','quality','high','scale','noscale','name','HTIFLVPlayer','salign','lt','pluginspage','http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer','wmode','transparent','movie','HTIFLVPlayer')</script>; 
    }
  }
}
</script>
<body onload="checkCookie()">
</body>
```

Comment: You are definitely missing quotes.  That is the place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you missing a few quotation marks there?

```
document.getElementById('video').innerHTML = <script type="text/javascript"> AC_FL_RunContent ('codebase','http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0','width','320','height','220','id','HTIFLVPlayer','src','HTIFLVPlayer','flashvars','&MM_ComponentVersion=1&skinName=HTI_Skin&streamName=nigel&autoPlay=true&autoRewind=true','quality','high','scale','noscale','name','HTIFLVPlayer','salign','lt','pluginspage','http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer','wmode','transparent','movie','HTIFLVPlayer')</script>; 

vs

document.getElementById('video').innerHTML = "<script type='text/javascript'> AC_FL_RunContent ('codebase','http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0','width','320','height','220','id','HTIFLVPlayer','src','HTIFLVPlayer','flashvars','&MM_ComponentVersion=1&skinName=HTI_Skin&streamName=nigel&autoPlay=true&autoRewind=true','quality','high','scale','noscale','name','HTIFLVPlayer','salign','lt','pluginspage','http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer','wmode','transparent','movie','HTIFLVPlayer')</script>";
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things that may or may not lead you the answer:

Check that the returned value from *getElementById* is not null before trying to use it, e.g.:

```
var el = document.getElementById('video')
if (el) {
  el.innerHTML = ...
}
```

Setting a script element as the innerHTML of an element will not execute the script.

The best way to do that is to put the script into a separate file and load it using the src property of the script element, e.g.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'videoScript.js';  // or whatever you call the script file
el.appendChild(script);
```

Alternatively, you can set the script as the script element's .text property, but that will not work in some browsers:

```
script.text = '...';
el.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. Using the solution from  Ӫ_._Ӫ  above, it at least no longer errors in the console, but as you suggested, it doesn't actually execute the script. I see what you're saying about putting the script into a seperate js file, but (excuse ignorance) don't understand quite how to formulate the script in the file - any chance you could elaborate a bit for me. Many many thanks, Rob.

Comment: Save the script in a plain text file, give it a .js extension (just makes life easier), put it somewhere on your server where you keep such resources, its URI becomes the script's *src* property.

Comment: Hi Rob, Thanks again. I've done what you suggested (I think) but in the error console, it now says "A call to document.write() from an asynchronously-loaded external script was ignored.  (and it doesn't play the video). Any suggestions greatfully received! Thanks, Rob.

Comment: If you call *document.write* after the page has finished loading, it first calls *document.clear*, removing **all** content. I didn't say use *docment.write*, I said to use either the *src* property or assign the script as a text string to the script element's *text* property before adding it to the document.

Comment: ...That's the weird thing, I'm not.  In the .js file, it just has the line of code that starts: AC_FL_RunContent  and ends with a semicolon, and the four lines of code in the cookie section are: `var el = document.getElementById('video');`
`var script = document.createElement('script');`
`script.src = 'videoScript.js';`  
`el.appendChild(script);`     and that's all I've changed.